# How to create these parallax animation

Tags: html, css, scroll, parallax

I refered to the following website: trov.com

```
data-20p-top="transform:translateY(-90%) translateX(-50%) scale(0.7) rotate(0deg); position: absolute; opacity: 1;"
```

How to create the scroll animation with the help of HTML5 & CSS3?

Comment: pls refer this website trov.com, i need this website animation

Answer (score 1):

I recommend doing some online research and you would well on your way to creating your desired website. here is good place to start. https://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/.

Answer (score 0):

More behind is more blur and small,this is how our `eye` see things
https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/qjfwmav0/